# Yellow tip polarity

Tags: adapter

What does the yellow tip on some adapters mean vs the blue or silver[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Usually adaptors have a label that identifies the connector pinout, voltage and amps available to use.

Comment: That looks like one of a dozen different size adapters that have different colors. The colours never meant anything to me except  easier to find when you have one that fits.

Answer (score 1):

It means nothing, it's just a colour of plastic.

Comment: Usually diameter of outside/inside, or if it has spring contacts. But there is no agreed standard, and conventions may vary from manufacturer to manufacturer. As for polarity, almost all are positive inside. However, in the past (last century), many used to be ground inside, so it is better to check before use.

Comment: yes some sets of changable tips are colour coded. SFAIK Panasonic always  uses ground inside and most others don't.

Comment: I did have a transformer based panasonic adapter with ground inside. Not sure if it's still true for the new smps based ones.

Comment: I've owned 4 panasonic cordless phones, they're all the same WRT polarity.

Comment: Always test for polarity with a multimeter - **never** assume... I was asked to look at an external hard drive, toast because they had used the wrong power supply... Reason was “well it fitted in the hole...”.